# How to get multiple ressources using one URI?

Tags: tastypie

When I issue this curl command: 
`curl http://localhost/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/?format=json -s | jq .`
I get:

```
{
    "objects":[
    { 
      "vehicle_id": 9759,
      "resource_uri": "/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/9759/",
      "noArticle": "",
      "name": "OBCIV_TFT2",
      "mac": "84:7e:40:e9:f2:1e"
    },
    {
      "vehicle_id": 9899,
      "resource_uri": "/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/9899/",
      "noArticle": "",
      "name": "FILM_FRONT",
      "mac": "00:40:9d:a2:36:fe"
    },
    {
      "vehicle_id": 9899,
      "resource_uri": "/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/9899/",
      "noArticle": "",
      "name": "OBCIV_TFT1",
      "mac": "84:7e:40:ea:a4:36"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total_count": 3,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 0
  }
}
```

I would like to get two ressources about the vehicle_id: 9899

to get something like this:

```
{
    "objects":[
    {
      "vehicle_id": 9899,
      "resource_uri": "/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/9899/",
      "noArticle": "",
      "name": "FILM_FRONT",
      "mac": "00:40:9d:a2:36:fe"
    },
    {
      "vehicle_id": 9899,
      "resource_uri": "/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/9899/",
      "noArticle": "",
      "name": "OBCIV_TFT1",
      "mac": "84:7e:40:ea:a4:36"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total_count": 2,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 0
  }
}
```

the problem I'm facing is that
`curl http://localhost/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/9899/?format=json -s`
returns:
`More than one resource is found at this URI.`

How to return multiple ressources having ressource_uri ?

I looked at the doc but I don't understand how to achieve this ..

Here's my api.py

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from refeq.models import VehiclesEquipements

USE_LOCAL_TIME = True

class MyDateSerializer(Serializer):
    def format_datetime(self, data):
        return data.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

class VehiclesEquipementsResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = VehiclesEquipements.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'vehiclesequipements'
        #filtering = {"vehicle_id":["exact","in"]}
        authorization=Authorization()
        limit = 0
        max_limit = 0
        if USE_LOCAL_TIME:
            serializer = MyDateSerializer()
```

and models.py

```
class VehiclesEquipements(models.Model):
    vehicle_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    noArticle = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vw_vehicles_equipements'
        managed = False
```

Final note: 
I cannot use uri filtering:

```
curl 'http://dope-apipc01/refeq/v1/vehiclesequipements/?format=json&vehicle_id__exact=9899'
```

I am newbie to Django and tastypie... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like to access a ressource it has to have a unique `resource_uri` otherwise exception `MultipleObjectsReturned` is returned.